# Javascript - String of a Byte with all combinations possible

Tags: javascript

i have a sting with a byte in it ("00001011") and now id like to get a array with all possible combinations of the 1 (acitve) "bits" in it also as a "byte string"
so from

var bString = "00001011"; //outgoing string

to a array with all string in it with all possible combinations of this "byte string" like - "00000001", "00000011", "00000010" and so on

is that possible?

thank you in advance

Comment: your required output is unclear - how many values are you expecting for the example input (I'm guessing 7 different outputs for the example, but not sure) - also, is the order important? why is 0011 before 0010 for instance

Comment: the output should be exact how many combinations are possible so here the 7 but also  all for this string ""11001011" and so on so for the whole byte

Comment: Can you write a full example output?

Comment: so you really want all 8 bit numbers other than 0, so 1 to 255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function combinations( input ){
   var number = parseInt( input, 2 );
   var combinations = [];
   var zeroes = (new Array(input.length)).join(0);
   for(var i=1;i<=number;i++){
     if((i&number) == i){ combinations.push( i ) }
   }
   return combinations.map( function(dec){
      return  (zeroes + dec.toString(2)).substr( -zeroes.length-1 );
   });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkf7pfxn/3/

```
console.log( combinations("00001011") );
// ["00000001", "00000010", "00000011", "00001000", "00001001", "00001010", "00001011"]
```

The idea goes as follows: iterate all numbers from 1 to the input number. If current number AND input number return the current number then both have `1` bits in the same place.

On a smaller number, `"0101"` (which is `5`) it works as follows:

`1 & 5 == 1`, (000**1** & 010**1**) push `1` to the matches.

`2 & 5 == 0`, (00**1**0 & 01**0**1) no match.

`3 & 5 == 1`, (00**1**1 & 01**0**1) no match.

`4 & 5 == 4`, (0**1**00 & 0**1**01) push `4` to the matches.

`5 & 5 == 5`, (0**1**0**1** & 0**1**0**1**) push `5` to the matches.

So the combinations for `0101` are `1` (`0001`), `2` (`0010`), `4` (`0100`) and `5` (`0101`).

Then there's this little trick to pad numbers with zeroes:

```
var zeroes = (new Array(input.length)).join(0); // gives a long enough string of zeroes
```

then

```
 // convert to base 2, add the zeroas at the beginning, 
 // then return the last n characters using negative value for substring
 return (zeroes + dec.toString(2)).substr( -1 * zeroes.length);
```

Comment: That's what I thought he wanted - except I think he wants `for(var i=1;i<=number;i++){` - because he did say "7" combinations for the example input

Comment: I also think you need `var zeroes = (new Array(input.length + 1)).join(0);` - because your output is 1 digit short : +1 for the fact that your code is adaptable to different input lengths

Comment: the outgoing string is missing then all 7 possibilities are in there (all zeros are not needed)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your suggestions, included them in my answer.

Comment: `-1 * zeroes.length + 1` should be `-1 * zeroes.length - 1` or `-1 * (zeroes.length + 1)` or simply `-(zeroes.length + 1)` or `-zeroes.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since `11111111` is 255 so just loop all values and convert them to binary

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    $('#core').append('<div>' + dec2bin(i) + '</div>');
  }

  function dec2bin(dec) {
    return ('00000000' + (dec >>> 0).toString(2)).slice(-8);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='core'></div>
```

Comment: i had only javascript possible and no jquery is there also a way?

Comment: the jqueery is only used for (lazy) outputing, it's not required for the "algorithm"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enumerate all combinations of binary numbers where `1` can only be in the place of your pattern, you can write a simple recursive function:

```js
var input = "00010111";
var current = [];

function combinations()
{
    if (input.length === current.length)
    {
        var output = current.join('');
        if (parseInt(output, 2) !== 0) // exclude all-zeroes case
            document.body.innerHTML += output + "<br/>";
        return;
    }    
    
    current.push('0'); 
    combinations();
    current.pop();
    
    if (input[current.length - 1] === '1') 
    {
        current.push('1');
        combinations();
        current.pop();
    }
}

combinations();
```

This algorithm works well for `input` of any length.
Although it is a recursion, it has a linear time complexity.